# Best way to download large files from web to iPhone for writing to disk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In an iPhone app I currently have code for downloading a file from the Web to the iPhone and saving it to disk.

The problem is that if the file is *large* then the memory usage of the app skyrockets and the app crashes.

I am sure I am just not doing it the "proper" way.

Currently I have the following:

```
mediaData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[mediaData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
[mediaData release];
```

As I mentioned this works for something like a picture, but not for something like say a video clip, as the app crashes.

What is the proper way to do this to keep my app from crashing?
My thought was maybe sockets, but as I have not done much socket programming, I am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) which runs asynchronously and delivers data in manageable chunks.

Comment: You would also want to use an API like NSFileHandle to write the data to disk as it comes in.

Of course for a video clip, would you not be better off using the movie player's built-in downloading support?

Comment: No because it will not allow you to save the video for future use

Comment: NSURLConnection with NSFileHandle was the answer. NSURLConnection alone still crashed.

Answer (score 2):

As `NSURLDownload` is not available on the iPhone, you might want to use `NSURLConnection` and buffer some data in a `NSMutableData` using `connection:didReceiveData:` delegate method. This article describes some of this: http://dannyg.com/iapps/Blog/Entries/2009/2/16_The_Joy_in_Discovering_You_Are_an_Idiot.html