# What is a good 'chunk size' for 'streaming' audio files?

Tags: php, audio, stream

I am using some code from another answer to stream audio over http - but don't know what 'chunksize' would be best... The files can be very large, and are streamed to an audio tag on a web page, I'd like a quick start up... The files are mainly .wav and .mp3

```
function streamfile($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) {
    $CHUNK_SIZE = 1024*1024; // Size (in bytes) of tiles chunk
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt =0;
    // $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $CHUNK_SIZE);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if ($retbytes) {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }
    }
    $status = fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $status) {
        return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540725/optimal-buffer-size-for-read-process-write will help you

Comment: Cheers it is a bit general, I found this too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398406/ideal-chunk-size-for-writing-streamed-content-to-disk-on-iphone - but looks like my server isn't streaming at all(!)

Answer (score 1):

All advice seems to be 'suck it and see'!

I tried a range of sizes from 1k to 1024k getting various results, but nothing remarkable.

I also experimented with variable block sizes - get some out quick to get the track playing and use that time to send bigger blocks - but again its, trial and error.

I also had to tweek various settings to stop PHP/webserver etc from 'helpfully' doing their own caching!

I have settled on 512k for now... seems as good as any(!).

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux System if you monitor the System Activity with the Command `strace` you will soon find out where the limitations of your script are.
For example monitoring the Performance of a `curl` Request you might find that the Bandwidth is the limitating Factor.
It might show for Example:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 41
fcntl(41, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(41, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
connect(41, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("<some.ip>")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
sendto(41, "GET /some-service/some"..., 3480, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 3480
recvfrom(41, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nTransaction-Id:"..., 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 14720
recvfrom(41, "\332\347\330Y\271\263F\314\7\225\271\264[16b\336_\346B[\n\350\336\210\371\10\371\226\373:\363"..., 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 16384
recvfrom(41, "\255W\23@\10\325\365A<\26\1\4\\\246\252\347\350\17\346kH\250\\&`BU\337\352\346m\225"..., 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 12223
close(41)                               = 0
```

In this Example you see that you received 3 packages of 14, 16 and 12 kB with an upper Limit of 16kB by default.
The first Packages is not filled because of bandwidth limitations that do not permit to fill up the internal buffer in the required reading time limit.
If you want to change the internal chunk limit of the PHP Engine you can do that with:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
stream_set_chunk_size($handle, $CHUNK_SIZE);
stream_set_read_buffer($handle, $CHUNK_SIZE);
```